# How to get this element from this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $arr that when I var_dump looks like this. What's the easiest way to get the 2nd last item ('simple' in this case). I can't do $arr[4] because the number of items may vary per url, and I always want just the 2nd last. (note that there's an extra empty string at the end, which will always be there.)

```
array
  0 => string 'http:' (length=5)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string 'site.com'
  3 => string 'group'
  4 => string 'simple'
  5 => string 'some-test-url'
  6 => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: Why not just ask "How do I get the last component of a URL in a string?" [instead](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: Note that second to last and `$arr[4]` are not the same thing. Unless I'm crazy, I would think that `$arr[4]` is third to last.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams It's not the last. It's the 2nd last or even the 3rd last if you count the last empty string as an item.

Comment: As a side note but a very important one: if this is your structure, you should create a Url class for it.  I'm sure you have functions that manipulate this array, so they should be methods of your url class. Our coding is often so lax in PHP; as a community we need to get better at using well-proven and structured techniques.

Answer (score 3):

So long as it is not a keyed or hashed array and it has more than two items...

```
$arr[count($arr) - 2];
```

**Note:** that my interpretation of second to last is second from the end. This may differ from yours. If so, subtract 3.

Answer (score 2):

Get the count and subtract 3?

```
$arr[count($arr)-3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!empty($arr) && count($arr)>1){
  //or > 2, -3 for your extra ending
  $val = $arr[count($arr)-2];
}
```

Should help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$second_last = count($array) - 3;

$value = $array[$second_last];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayLen=count($arr);
echo $arr[$arrayLen-2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative:

```
echo current(array_slice($data, -3, 1));
```